# Javascript not executing. No console errors, no validation errors

Tags: javascript, html, submit

When I hit my submit button it just goes straight to the php page. The javascript does not load at all. This is very confusing because I am receiving no errors in console nor when I validate the javascript using external error checkers (such as JShint). The javascript was working at one point in my coding so I have no idea why it stopped working.

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
//jQuery

$(document).ready(function() {

    // listen for a click event on any radio element

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

        // get the id of the clicked element
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        // fade out any existing image elements
        $('img').fadeOut(800, function() {

            // fade in the image element with the id we're after, with a half second delay (500 milliseconds)
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#' + id + 'i').fadeIn(800);

            }, 500);
        });

    });

});

function checkInput() {

    var firstName = document.getElementById("fn");
    var lastName = document.getElementById("ln");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");
    var emailR = document.getElementById("emailR");
    var postal = document.getElementById("pc");
    var city = document.getElementById("city");
    var sA = document.getElementById("sA");
    var qN = document.getElementById("qty");
    var provy = document.getElementById("prov");
    var foc = false;

    var error = "";



    var letters = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var numbers = /^\d+$/;
    var letNm = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])/;

    //First-Name Validation

    if (firstName.value == "" || firstName.value.length > 15 || firstName.value.length < 2 || !firstName.value.match(letters)) {
        error += "\n  Please enter a valid first name.";
        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementById("fn").focus();
            foc = true;
        }
    }


    //Last-Name Validation

    if (lastName.value == "" || lastName.value.length > 15 || lastName.value.length < 2 || !lastName.value.match(letters)) {
        error += "\n  Please enter a valid last name";
        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementById("ln").focus();
            foc = true;
        }
    }


    //street Address
    if (sA.value == "" || sA.value.length < 6 || sA.value.length > 30 || !sA.value.match(letNm)) {
        error += "\n  Please enter a valid street address (must contain letters and numbers, \n  and be more than 6 less than 30 chars) ";
        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementById("sA").focus();
            foc = true;
        }

    }
    //City Validation
    if (city.value == "" || city.value.length > 20 || city.value.length < 2 || !city.value.match(letters)) {
        error += "\n Please enter a valid city (more than 2 characters, less than 20, all letters)";
        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementById("city").focus();
            foc = true;

        }

    }

    //Province Validation
    var select = provy.options[provy.selectedIndex].value;
    if (select == "s") {
        error += "\n Please choose a province";

        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementsByName("prov").focus();
            foc = true;

        }


    }


    //Email Validation

    var ei = email.value.lastIndexOf('@');
    var dot = email.value.lastIndexOf('.');

    if (email.value == "" || email.value.length < 7 || email.value.length > 50 || ei == -1 || dot == -1 || dot < ei + 2) {

        error += "\n  Please enter a valid email address \n     (must have an \"@\" symbol followed by a \".\")";
        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
            foc = true;
        }
    } else if (emailR.value != email.value) {
        error += "\n  Your email addresses did not match";
        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementById("emailR").focus();
            foc = true;
        }
    }


    //Postal Code Validation

    var pi = postal.value.lastIndexOf(" ");
    var code = /^[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z][ -]?\d[A-Za-z]\d$/;

    if (postal.value == "" || postal.value.length != 7 || !postal.value.match(code) || pi != 3) {
        error += "\n  Please enter a valid Canadian postal code. E.g. \"N3H 1M1\" ";
        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementById("pc").focus();
            foc = true;
        }
    }



    //Album selection Validation
    var jay = document.getElementsById("jayz");

    if (!isOneChecked(jay)) {
        error += "\n  Please choose an album to purchase";
        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementsByName("jayz").focus();
            foc = true;
        }

    }
    //quantity validation


    if (qN.value == "" || qN.value > 99 || qN.value < 1 || !qN.value.match(numbers)) {
        error += "\n  Please enter a quantity between 1-99";
        if (foc == false) {
            document.getElementByName("qntty").focus();
            foc = true;
        }

    }



    //error validation:error2 boolean returns either true or false
    var error2 = false;

    if (foc == false) {
        alert("Thank you for signing up!");
        error2 = true;
    } else {
        alert(error);
        error2 = false;
    }
    return error2;

}

//function that trims and converts string to properCase
function properCaseTrim(string) {
    var str = string.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < str; i++) {
        var letter = string.charAt(i);
        if (letter == " ") {
            string = string.replace(/^\s\s*/, ''); // Remove Preceding white space
            string = string.replace(/\s\s*$/, ''); // Remove Trailing white space
        }
        string = string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    }

    return string;
}

function isOneChecked() {
    // All <input> tags...
    var chx = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < chx.length; i++) {
        // Return true from the function on first match of a checked item
        if (chx[i].type == 'radio' && chx[i].checked) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // End of the loop, return false
    return false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Assignment #4</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favi.ico" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
        <script type ="text/javascript" src="javascript/function.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Jay-Z Albums</h1>
        </header>
        <fieldset id = "field1">
            <legend>Shipping Info</legend>
            <p id ="p">All Fields Are Mandatory </p>
            <form method = "post" name= "user creation form" onsubmit="return checkInput();" action = "php/validate.php">
                First name<br>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id ="fn"  onblur="this.value = properCaseTrim(this.value)" value= "" autofocus><br>
                Last name<br>
                <input type="text" name="lastName" id = "ln" onblur="this.value = properCaseTrim(this.value)" value= ""><br>
                Street Address<br>
                <input type="text" name="streetAddress" id = "sA" placeholder="123 Main St." onblur="this.value = properCaseTrim(this.value)" value= "" ><br>
                <label>
                    City <br>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" onblur="this.value = properCaseTrim(this.value)" value= "">
                </label>
                <br>
                Province <br>
                <select name ="prov" id ="prov">
                    <option value = "s">-select-</option>
                    <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
                    <option value="British Columbia">British Columbia</option>
                    <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
                    <option value="New Brunswick">New Brunswick</option>
                    <option value="Newfoundland and Labrador">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
                    <option value="Nova Scoti">Nova Scotia</option>
                    <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
                    <option value="Prince Edward Island">Prince Edward Island</option>
                    <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
                    <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
                    <option value="Northwest Territories">Northwest Territories</option>
                    <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
                    <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label>
                    Postal Code <br>
                    <input type="text" name="pc" id="pc"  placeholder="A1A 1A1" onblur="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase(); this.value = properCaseTrim(this.value)" value= ""> <br>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Email Address<br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email"  value= ""> <br>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Repeat Email Address <br>
                    <input type="text" name="emailR" id="emailR" value= "" > <br>
                </label>
                <br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id = "field3">
                <legend>Order </legend>
                <p> One Album Per Order</p>
                <p> Prices shown are without tax </p>
                <input type = "radio" name ="jayz" value="rDbt" id= "rD">[1996]Reasonable Doubt-$25 <br>
                <input type = "radio" name ="jayz" value="bPrint" id= "bP1">[2001]The Blueprint-$10<br>
                <input type = "radio" name ="jayz" value="bPrint2" id = "bP2">[2002]The Blueprint 2-$15<br>
                <input type = "radio" name ="jayz" value="kCome" id ="kC">[2006]Kingdom Come-$10<br>
                <input type = "radio" name ="jayz" value="bPrint3" id ="bP3">[2009]The Blueprint  3-$25<br>
                <input type = "radio" name ="jayz" value="mCarta" id ="mC">[2013]Magna Carta Holy Grail-$30<br>
                <div id="q">
                    # of Albums:
                    <input type="text" name="quant" id="qty">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <aside>
                <div id = "divvy">
                    <img  class = "hidden" src="images/rDoubt.jpg" alt="Reasonable Doubt" height="400px" width="400px" id= "rDi">
                    <img class = "hidden" src="images/bPrint.jpg" alt="the Blueprint" height="400px" width="400px" id= "bP1i">
                    <img  class = "hidden" src="images/bPrint2.jpg" alt="the Blueprint 2" height="400px" width="400px" id = "bP2i">
                    <img class = "hidden"  src="images/kCome.jpg" alt="Kingdom Come" height="400px" width="400px"  id ="kCi">
                    <img  class = "hidden" src="images/bPrint3.jpg" alt="the Blueprint 3" height="400px" width="400px"  id ="bP3i">
                    <img  class = "hidden" src="images/mCarta.jpg" alt="Magna Carta" height="400px" width="400px" id ="mCi">
                </div>
            </aside>
            <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit Order" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first `fieldset` belongs inside the `form`, not before it.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of these script tags: (The jquery one should be first)

```
 <script type ="text/javascript" src="javascript/function.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
```

I suspect your jquery code in function.js is not working due to this issue.

Comment: I did that the javascript still doesn't run :/

Comment: Maybe cached? try hitting Cmd+R (mac) or Ctrl+R on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the default behavior of `<input type="submit"/>`, you have to override it:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.prevetDefault();
    //do your JS processing here, call a function and finally make an AJAX request
checkInput();
});
```

That should do.

On a separate note, I dont think 'name' attribute with spaces is valid. It is best to be kept unique/ or treat as a key or identifier.